# How does this save my form from csrf attack?

Tags: php, token, csrf, csrf-protection

I have this form

```
<form>
//code
<input type="hidden" value="gfth35rfer43556thgrth8678gbfgb" name="csrf">
</form>
```

Token is unique for every user. Now suppose attacker is logged in and open this page. Now he knows what current session token is , by copying the value above the attacker has authentication token. He can attack my site easily. How does this procedure prevents csrf attack?

Comment: Read up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: A good rule of thumb when asking about a new topic is to view the highest voted questions from both categories: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+csrf?sort=votes&pageSize=50. You'll get a nice introduction and see the biggest problems and solutions in the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

- Alice - a user
- Bob - someone who runs a site
- Mallory - an attacker

The point of CSRF protection is to prevent Mallory from tricking Alice into submitting data provided by Mallory (using Alice's user credentials).

Since Alice and Mallory have different tokens, Mallory cannot just "copy the value above".

It isn't there to prevent Mallory submitting data using their own credentials. To solve that problem you need to decide how much trust to give to different users.

Comment: nice explanation tnx. How can i stop users from submitting form from another website to mine. If you have any link explaining this that would be helpful

Comment: To what end? To stop them being tricked into submitting data they don't want to send? That's what CSRF protection will do. To stop them submitting data you don't want them to submit? You can't prevent that. You need to check the sanity of the data when it arrives on your server.